# Browser based video conversion before uploading to server

Tags: java, flash, video-conversion

I want something either flash or java based (in otherwords anything that will run from the browser without having to the user download some other program, and doesn't have to have winblows) that can compress a video before it gets uploaded to the server. I plan on doing the heavy lifting server-side via ffmpeg, but the client should at least be able to compress down to a reasonable size, before it even goes to the server, otherwise it would take forever to upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers are very limited in terms of access to the user's filesystem. To do what you want to, you can write a Java Applet that does the compression at client's end before uploading it via an active FTP connection(all this should happen behind the scenes, without the user knowing it). The Java applet must be signed and certified, and should be allowed to access your filesystem(set the required security permissions).

Once you receive it onto your server system, you should decompress and convert before storing it into your central repository of streamable videos.